# how to do a game that is simulated by a loop

Tags: game-loop

how to do program a game that is simulated by a loop in which people has to repeat goes for as long as it takes to get out that it reach or pass square 80? I am doing a snake & ladder game and need to write a code that will allow this to happen

Comment: This question is unanswerable. Please provide more context and tell us what have already done and what is not working. This is not a 'tell us what you want and we will program it for you' kind of place.

Comment: I understand that it is about a game....

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a loop with an exit condition that checks if a player has reached square 80 or otherwise won.

```
while ( !hasPlayerWon() ) {

    //continue game

}
```

[loops in javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_while.asp), [loops in C++](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson3.html) :D